# How to show Popup by clicking the XML Menu link in Devexpress asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, popup, devexpress-mvc

I'm facing a little problem.
I'm working with VS 2015 with DEVExpress (ASP.NET MVC).
In my application I have menu generated but XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<items>
  <item Text="ACCUEIL" NavigateUrl="#"/>
  <item Text="EP" NavigateUrl="#"/>
  <item Text="NOUVELLE DEMANDE" NavigateUrl = ""/>
</items>
```

For my last menu item, I want to show popup when user click on it, not go to another page like normal.

I have search and try some solution like create a `ActionResult` that return `PartialView` but not succeed doing what I want.
Has someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add names to your items on the XML menu configuration then on your menu settings add a client side event on the `ItemClick` event :

```
settings.ClientSideEvents.ItemClick = "function(s, e) { /* if(e.item[0].name == 'NOUVELLE_DEMANDE') { /* Do whatever you want to here */} */ }";
```